# How do you create a ClickOnce MS Office Outlook add-in?

Tags: c#, outlook, clickonce, ms-office, add-in

The Outlook add-ins I have created using Visual Studio 2005 don't use the ClickOnce installer, just the regular Windows Installer.

(File -> New Project -> Extensibility -> Shared Add-In)

I need to create the add-ins using the ClickOnce installer because as far as I know that's the only way there is to sign the add-ins so they can run in spite of Macro Security settings on the clients' computers.

Can someone tell me how to create an Outlook add-in installer using ClickOnce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an installer project to your solution.  That will install the application to your program files directory which is trusted by default.  It will require the end user to have admin privileged to install, but it does not require the installer files to be signed.  It is not technically a click-once install, but it works very well for office add-ins.

**Edit:** You also need to add a reference to the addin to the registry. Check out [Deploying a Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Solution Using
Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) on MSDN.  Figure 6 and the instructions preceding it describe how this is done.

The actual values to add to the registry key can be a bit confusing, so here are the ones that I used which work fine:

- Description: `"Provides functionality to access data from ..."`
- FriendlyName: `"CompanyTools"`
- LoadBehavior: `3` (indicates that the add-in should be loaded at startup of the host application)
- Manifest: `"file:///[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]/[ProductName]/T360.Office.CompanyTools.vsto|vstolocal"`

Also, I think that you need to add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll as a dependency. I don't think that it is by default.

Comment: the solution already comes with an installer, since I'm using a template. I still cannot get this to work.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention the registry keys that you need to add.  I added a link to MSDN in the answer with that info, along with some notes on how I pulled it off.

Comment: That's interesting. My compiled solution does not have a .vsto file and I don't seem to be able to locate the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Application.Runtime.dll in Solution Explorer when I click on Add References. I searched under COM and .NET and could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project properties/Signing tab. Check "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" and provide your signing certificate.

Now go to the Publish tab. You need to fill in the publishing file location, which should be a URL or a file share. If the installation location is the same as the publish location, you can leave it blank.

Click the Prerequisites button and make sure the necessary prerequisites are selected.

Click the Updates button and pick how frequently to check or updates.

Click Options. Fill in the publisher name (typically your company), product name (how you want it to look in the uninstall page, and in the Add-Ins list in the Office product), and a support URL if you want.  Check the Office Settings, too.

Fill in a publish version.

Click Publish Now. It will publish your deployment to the publishing file location.

You should be able to use the installation URL or publishing location to install the add-in. Note that if you have the Office product running, you need to close it and re-open it to load the add-in.

Comment: That doesn't work because the Sign the ClickOnce manifests option is not available.

Comment: I don't have VS2005. If there is no option for signing the C/O manifests, then it must sign them by default. Have you tried doing this w/o that step?